# How to send post parameter from wicket page to jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets, wicket-1.5

My application is mix of wicket and jsp pages . There is a requirement in which i have    to   send my selected check box ids  from wicket to jsp page . 
i dont want to use session . please suggest some other ways

Comment: Put them in as request attributes and then hide them in hidden inputs in the jsp.

Comment: could you please add little more explanation here as what hidden inputs in jsp if i will able to get there then its all done . thanks

Comment: You usually use session attributes to keep data alive between requests. If you don't want to do that, you have to constantly send it through requests. A way to do this is to store the ids in an `<input type="hidden">` field and retrieve it in the next request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i got the solution in my case i should have used the container request . because in previous condition the wicket request was different that normal request as my application is mixture of wicket and jsp